# Radio buttons to new page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hey guys sorry to ask this, but I am stumped, I want the code to go to the pages with the action when the radio button is clicked, like stupid radio button to stupid.php here's the form

```
<form name = "quoted" method="get">
    <input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" required="required" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">     
    <br>
    <textarea class = "actual_quote" name = "actual_quote" required="required" placeholder = "Write the question here!"></textarea>
    <br><br><br>

    <div class = "checkboxes" required="required">
        <h3 style = "margin-top:-20px;">Please select one catagory that the quote falls into.</h3>
        <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupid" id = "x" checked="checked" action = "stupid.php" /><span>stupid</span></label>
        <br>
        <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupider" id = "x" action = "stupider.php" /><span>stupider</span></label>
        <br>
        <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupidest" id = "x" action = "stupidest.php" /><span>stupidest</span></label>
    </div>

    <input id = "submit1" type="submit"><br>
 </form>
```

and here's the php on each of the pages, stupid, stupider, and stupidest, the php error is saying that actual-quote and poster are not identified indexes, help?

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="submissions">
    <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Question.</h2>
    <div class="checkboxes"><?= !empty($_GET['x']) ? $_GET['x'] : '' ?>
    </div>

    </div>

 <div class="top-submit"><?php echo '&#8220;' . (!empty($_GET['actual_quote']) ?  $_GET['actual_quote'] : '') . '&#8221;'; $actual_quote = $_GET['actual_quote'];?>
 </div>
 <div class="poster"><?php echo "-" .  (!empty($_GET['poster']) ? $_GET['poster'] :''); $poster =  $_GET['poster'];?>
 <div class = "like">
 <a href = "javascript:countClicksLike();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "color:green;">Like</a>
 <p id = "like" style = "color:green;">0</p>
 </div>
 <div class = "dislike">
 <a href = "javascript:countClicks();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "float:right; color:red;">Dislike</a>
 <p id = "dis" style = "color:red;">0</p>
 </div>
  </div>
 <?php 
 "INSERT INTO submissions(top-submit, poster)
 VALUES ($actual_quote, $poster)";
?>
</div>
</div>
```

I am sorry to ask, but I have been trying for an hour and I have run out of ideas. Any suggestions is GREATLY welcomed.

Just to clarify, I want each of the radio buttons, when selected, to a new page once they click the submit button, i want to have them check one radio option, and then click submit and be directed to the page.
v

Comment: check my answer and here is the demo http://jsbin.com/sumax/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sumax/1/edit)**

```
 <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupid" id = "x" checked="checked" action = "stupid.php" />    <span>stupid</span></label><br>
```

Based on your radio buttons,

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
         window.location.href = $(this).attr("action"); 
});
```

So when the user clicks on any one of the radio buttons, the click handler will take him to the respective page mentioned in the `action` attribute.

In case if you want to redirect only if the radio button is checked and not when its unchecked, use   `if($(this).is(":checked"))` to check the condition

Answer (score 0):

I fail to understand why are you not using `anchors` for redirecting instead of messing up with inputs. If you use anchors, then you don't need any custom attributes of action on inputs.

Moreover if you have a form then why not simply use it's action attribute for the purpose. And in the backend you can handle the redirect easily instead of relying on the javascript redirect.

Still, if you want to use inputs for navigation and redirecting and since you didn't mentioned anything about jQuery, I assume you need pure Javascript solution. You can use inline javascript in the inputs like:

```
<label><input type="radio" action="http://www.google.com" onclick="window.location.href=this.action;"  />Google</label>
```

If you need a jQuery solution, refer to the solution provided above by mohamedrias.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to post values to different php files based on the selection of radio button. If yes, I think you can achieve the same using jquery.

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
$("form").attr('action',$(this).attr('action'));
});
```

The above code will add click event handlers to all the radio buttons. When the user clicks the radio button, the action property from the radio button will be set to the form. When the form is submitted, it will be calling the php file set in the action property of the currently selected radio button